# Does QuestDB support nanosecond timestamps and nanosecond timestamp generation?

Tags: questdb

Which precision does QuestDB support for timestamps?
1ns? 1μs? 1ms?

Which resolution can QuestDB generate timestamps at?
1ns? 100ns? 1ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuestDB does not support nanosecond timestamps.
It has 2 types to store date time data:

- `TIMESTAMP` is stored and generated with 1 microsecond precision
- `DATE` is stored and generated with 1 millisecond precision

There are plans to add nanosecond timestamp as far as I know.